# Use pytorch to heterogeneous computing

Tags: pytorch, parallel-processing

If pytorch defines a model where a layer has two branches, branch1 and branch2, how can the two branches be executed in parallel, one on the GPU and the other on the CPU?

Putting less computationally intensive on the CPU and more computationally intensive on the GPU

Comment: AFAIK if you have part of the model on CPU e.g. `m1.to('cpu')` and another on GPU `m2.to('cuda:0')`, then as long as they don't have to juggle the data between CPU and GPU, `m1` and `m2` will run asynchronously